Website: URL and folder with the same name does not work
I want to use the following URL:
my-domain.com/urlname
and have a directory in my webspace with the same name as the url.
In my htaccess I have the follwing RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^urlname$    landingpage.php [L,QSA] 
As soon as I add a folder to my webspace with the same name "urlname" I can't open the url anymore with my browser. When the folder "urlname" exists, Chrome automatically adds a trailing slash to the url and says "Access forbidden!".
Is it possible to have an url with the same name as a folder (which really exists, without using htaccess):
my-domain.com/urlname
my-domain.com/urlname/




When the folder "urlname" exists, Chrome automatically adds a trailing slash to the url and says "Access forbidden!"

That is because of 2 configs on your web server (Apache).

Module mod_dir runs before mod_rewrite module and checks for a trailing slash when request matches an existing directory. If there is a missing trailing / then it does a 301 redirect by adding a trailing /.
403 is due to presence of (recommended) Options  -Indexes somewhere in Apache config or in the same .htaccess it is disabling directory listing when there is no index file present. This is as per the security recommendations.

If you want to make it all work with minimal change then use:
RewriteRule ^urlname/?$ landingpage.php [L,NC]

Take note of the trailing / that matches URI urlname/.
Note that you will still get a 301 redirect if you enter URL as /urlname to the /urlname/ first then it will display content from landingpage.php.
I have removed unwanted flag QSA and added NC (ignore case) flag.

Thank you very much for your answer. Can I change/disable the behavior of mod_dir?

Yes you can disable this behavior by using DirectorySlash Off

Did this work out well?
